# Cannot Access memory error

Tags: gdb

I am trying to debug a simple buffer overflow program using gdb . I analyzed the program on windows without any issues .But now i am using linux gdb with exact same program but i am getting "Cannot access memory at address 0xffffffffffffdfa0" error while accessing esp and a variable.
[image]

Can anyone help me out
thanks

Comment: Include code as a text

Comment: Even when using RSP or SP keeps giving me the "Cannot access memory" error. Any help would be appriciated.

Answer (score 3):

Try examining `rsp` instead of `esp`.

```
 ax->16-bit
eax->32-bit
rax->64-bit
```

It is similar for stack pointer too. `sp`->16-bit, `esp`->32-bits and `rsp`->64-bit. When you are examining the esp, the address is actually 64 bits but you are trying examine and forcing it to split to 32 bits addresses.

[image]